# Have a question about react hook usage for "useEffect"

Tags: javascript

```
// ....react component

const [fruitDetail, setFruitDetail] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
    if (!fruitName) {
      return;
    }

    // Method 1
    getFruit(fruitName).then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      setFruitDetail(data);
    });

    // Method 2
    getFruit(fruitName).then(setFruitDetail);
}, [fruitName]);

return fruitDetail;
```

I'm very curious about that why Method 1 and Method 2 are equivalent. Is it a Syntactic sugar ?

Comment: This is not related to reactjs nor the useEffect hook. That's how passing functions as parameters works (setFruitDetail is a function and (data) => {...} is also a function).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at method 1 as an explicit way of calling the function. The `.then` method gets passed the result of `getFruit(fruitName)`..which you could name whatever you wanted, in your case you chose to call it `data`. Then you used that variable, `data` to make two function calls. So you explicitly refer the response by the variable name `data`.

In your method 2, the variable is implicit. Meaning, because of the way `.then` works, Javascript knows `.then` expects one argument, which is the result of the `getFruit(fruitName)`. The `.then` method takes the result and passes it as the first argument to `setFruitDetail`...it would also be the same thing to say `getFruit(fruitName).then(response => setFruitDetail(response))`.You just don't need to specifically put the `response` variable since it is the only thing being passed and only thing being used.

Answer (score 0):

`then` function calls any passed function/callback with the promise result.
`setFruitDetail` is just a function so is `()=>{}` albeit anonymous one. You can also pass `console.log` and see what it does like this `getFruit(fruitName).then(console.log)`. I would suggest to have a look at basic promise implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a Syntactic sugar ?

> No, it is not. Because, it's just the another way to pass callback function.

There is example to make clear:

```js
    let api = async () => {
        return new Promise((solve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() =>  solve('result'), 1000);
        })
    };
    
    //your setFruit is a callback. Let example:
    let setFruitDetail = (fruit) => console.log(fruit);

    //there is no different when you pass a call back into then function.
    api().then(setFruitDetail);
    api().then(fruit => setFruitDetail(fruit));
    
    
    //you can imagine that in then function will get param you input into to call a callback.
    let otherApi = (callback) => {
      let result = "result";
      
      callback("result");
    }

    otherApi(setFruitDetail);
    otherApi(fruit => setFruitDetail(fruit));
```